# Cannot open database in spring boot sql server connection

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I recently tried studying spring boot with JPA and SQL Server 2014 as my database. I have already completed a tutorial and everything was working fine. However, when I already started creating what I need, I keep getting this error that spring boot can't open my new database.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "actualApplication" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:5d1b140d-2a96-48ad-8a54-c5604bb46541
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:283) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:129) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:5233) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3988) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:85) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3932) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7375) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3206) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2713) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2362) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2213) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1276) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:861) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:330) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.getDefaultDdlAuto(HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.java:42) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.lambda$getVendorProperties$1(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:130) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:41) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineDdlAuto(HibernateProperties.java:136) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:102) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:94) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:132) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:134) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1159) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.actualApplication.productsservice.ProductsServiceApplication.main(ProductsServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
```

Here's some stuff that I think are worth mentioning:

First, I installed a new instance. I had my first instance which I used when I was studying Spring Boot. Now since I am about to create my own application, I installed a new instance so I can name it properly.

Here are my `application.properties` file for both of my tutorial app and actual app:

Tutorial app `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=demoApplication
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=somepassword
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

Actual app `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=actualApplication
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=somepassword
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

Second, both instances are currently running. I tried turning off my tutorial instance, but it didn't help. Third, the tutorial application is still working fine even after I have already installed a new instance of SQL Server.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You have two instances of SQL Server installed, how do the connections determine which SQL Server they should be connecting to? If the new instance has an instance name have you tried adding that to the connection properties?

Comment: See [What are named and default instances?](https://serverfault.com/q/80767/450280) on Server Fault.